# Missing .h and .c files in speech sdk 5.1

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, sapi

I have downloaded a speech sdk 5.1 from [microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121). In *Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1\Samples\CPP\Engines\SR* there is a project file **sreng.dsp**, which i want to compile.

In the code of file **"sreng.cpp"** there are included files, such as **"sreng.h"** and **"sreng_i.c"**, that appear missing, i.e. there are no such files anywhere on the computer and it appears to me that they don't come with the sdk, nor they can be found anywhere on internet.

The question is, can i get these files somewhere and if not, then how can i compile this project?

I am using visual studio 2013. and windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that files **"sreng.h"** and **"sreng_i.c"** are generated from **"sreng.idl"** file using *midl* compiler. After they are generated, there are no problems compiling a project.